# WOOF - Woocommerce Product Filter plugin customization

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can i modify template page of WOOF - Products Filter wordpress plugin. I have my child theme to implement. Like i have enable extension called By rating. I just want to change the dropdown value of By Rating filter options

Comment: Have you tried to place that template inside woocommerce folder of your child theme?

Comment: Yes but when i place the same name folder in my child theme it won't work

Comment: Have you placed that folder inside woocommerce?

Comment: no but it is another plugin so i have placed that folder in my child theme alone

Comment: try to place inside woocoomerce plugin

Comment: I have place inside woocommerce plugin but not working as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176213/discussion-between-bhavik-chudasama-and-sudharshan-nair).

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the values directly from the woof.php file, it is located under the following folder

plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/ext/by_rating/views

woof.php